# Can I customize Chrome / Chromium interface elements?

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extensions, user-interface, chromium

I've done a some searching and haven't seen a great solution for this yet. I want to customize some of the Chromuim UI elements. For example, hide location bar, hide tab bar, hide scroll bars, etc.

I've considered myself a committed Firefox user, but I'm beginning to become curious if I can like Chromium as much. With Firefox, UI elements can be tinkered on by CSS with the userChrome file as well as through the Stylish add on.

I see there is an addon for hiding the scroll bars via css. I know Stylish is available for Chrome / Chromium so can you mess with the UI?

Comment: One of the reasons I keep going back to Firefox from Chrome: the customization.

Comment: No, you can't yet.

Comment: @SathyajithBhat Have there been any changes since you wrote your comment over 7 years ago?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The devs have repeatedly indicated that they have no intention of letting users alter the physical dimensions of the browser chrome (ie, themes *only* change colors and textures), allowing elements to be moved, etc., by always closing such [requests](http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/list) and flagging them as **Won’t Fix**.

Chrome is already designed to use the minimal amount of chrome. If you really need to hide the Omnibar and tabs, you can use <kbd>F11</kbd> to go to fullscreen.

Comment: That's too bad. It seems trivial but I like my Firefox with Vimperator and all the chrome stripped out.